# Obtener ID (fragmento de Cadena) con función preg_match() PHP

Tags: php, regex, método, preg-match

Necesito obtener el ID que cambia constantemente (fragmento de Cadena) siguiente al carácter "/" de un String que contiene la URL de un dominio con la función `preg_match()` de PHP. Estuve leyendo acerca de las expresiones regulares que requiere esta función y no logré comprenderlo para hacer por mi mismo la expresión.

Voy a tratar de ser más claro con un ejemplo, muy similar a lo que yo busco (Lo único que cambiaría es el nombre de dominio)

Tengo las siguientes URLs en una variable tipo string PHP:

```html
$cadena = 'http://midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl https://midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl https://www.midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl http://www.midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl';
```

Y quiero extraer solamente la cadena resaltada en este caso **MiID1#23Deurl** usando la función `preg_match()` de PHP. También deseo que funcione con la misma cadena pero con el protocolo HTTPS en el mismo dominio ó usando el típico CNAME **www** para el dominio.

Comment: creo que con un simple explode en el `/` bastara para ontener un array de esa url y extraer la cadena deseada, tambien con preg_split: `preg_split('/(\/)/', $entrada, $salida);` creo que basta

Comment: Te comenté otra manera de hacerlo de una manera más sencilla.

Comment: @CarlosQuintero Intenté hacerlo con Preg_split pero con este regex no funciona. y con explode no me sirve porque me genera un array lleno de cadenas basura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado combinando funciones PHP, y aprendiendo (medianamente) a generar expresiones regulares, como se muestra a continuación:

```html
$cadena = 'http://midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl https://midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl https://www.midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl http://www.midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl';    
$regex_rdomain = '/\b(https?):\/\/[-a-zA-Z0-9.]+\//i';
$privateIDs = preg_replace($regex_rdomain,'',preg_split('/[\s]+/i',$cadena));
print_r($privateIDs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías resolverla , en lugar de hacerlo con expresiones regulares, realizando dos veces la función `list` y `explode`. Mira:

```
<?php 
    $cadena = 'http://midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl';

    $cadena2 = 'https://midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl';

    $cadena3 = 'https://www.midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl';

    $cadena4 = 'http://www.midominio.com/MiID1#23Deurl';

    list($dospuntosdoblediagonal, $restodelurl) = explode('://', $cadena);
    list($diagonal, $dominio) = explode('/', $restodelurl);

    echo $dominio;
?>
```

Pruébalo con cada uno de las cadenas para que veas que te regresa siempre el dominio. Saludos.